# Calculating net value of a row with condition on the column

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, rowsum

My dataframe has 2695 observations of 195 variables, and its first 100x10 quadrant looks like this:

```
structure(list(name = c("Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", 
"Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", "Albania", 
"Albania", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", 
"Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", 
"Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", 
"Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Andorra", 
"Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", 
"Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", 
"Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", "Andorra", 
"Andorra", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", 
"Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola", 
"Angola", "Angola", "Angola", "Angola"), code = c("AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", "AFG", 
"AFG", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", 
"ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", 
"ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "ALB", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", 
"DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", 
"DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "DZA", "AND", "AND", 
"AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", 
"AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", "AND", 
"AND", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", 
"AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO"), cluster = c("Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries", 
"Industries", "Industries", "Industries", "Industries"), sector = c("Agriculture", 
"Fishing", "Mining and Quarrying", "Textiles and Wearing Apparel", 
"Wood and Paper", "Petroleum, Chemical and Non-Metallic Mineral Products", 
"Metal Products", "Transport Equipment", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Electricity, Gas and Water", "Construction", "Maintenance and Repair", 
"Wholesale Trade", "Retail Trade", "Transport", "Post and Telecommunications", 
"Public Administration", "Education, Health and Other Services", 
"Private Households", "Others", "Re-export & Re-import", "Agriculture", 
"Fishing", "Mining and Quarrying", "Textiles and Wearing Apparel", 
"Wood and Paper", "Petroleum, Chemical and Non-Metallic Mineral Products", 
"Metal Products", "Transport Equipment", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Electricity, Gas and Water", "Construction", "Maintenance and Repair", 
"Wholesale Trade", "Retail Trade", "Transport", "Post and Telecommunications", 
"Public Administration", "Education, Health and Other Services", 
"Private Households", "Others", "Re-export & Re-import", "Agriculture", 
"Fishing", "Mining and Quarrying", "Textiles and Wearing Apparel", 
"Wood and Paper", "Petroleum, Chemical and Non-Metallic Mineral Products", 
"Metal Products", "Transport Equipment", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Electricity, Gas and Water", "Construction", "Maintenance and Repair", 
"Wholesale Trade", "Retail Trade", "Transport", "Post and Telecommunications", 
"Public Administration", "Education, Health and Other Services", 
"Private Households", "Others", "Re-export & Re-import", "Agriculture", 
"Fishing", "Mining and Quarrying", "Textiles and Wearing Apparel", 
"Wood and Paper", "Petroleum, Chemical and Non-Metallic Mineral Products", 
"Metal Products", "Transport Equipment", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Electricity, Gas and Water", "Construction", "Maintenance and Repair", 
"Wholesale Trade", "Retail Trade", "Transport", "Post and Telecommunications", 
"Public Administration", "Education, Health and Other Services", 
"Private Households", "Others", "Re-export & Re-import", "Agriculture", 
"Fishing", "Mining and Quarrying", "Textiles and Wearing Apparel", 
"Wood and Paper", "Petroleum, Chemical and Non-Metallic Mineral Products", 
"Metal Products", "Transport Equipment", "Other Manufacturing", 
"Electricity, Gas and Water", "Construction", "Maintenance and Repair", 
"Wholesale Trade", "Retail Trade", "Transport", "Post and Telecommunications"
), Total = c(313056.134909551, 1269.32391427775, 6702.10091092139, 
20822.9824174335, 3277.35295343427, 7075.57751406419, 5809.54856404444, 
6374.97667034069, 6573.16606009056, 1520.47502801121, 10658.977916637, 
7414.61509425962, 12290.7967126299, 11398.2992559452, 40272.8802077045, 
11195.0970347162, 9608.34006394526, 15892.9447789989, 7520.16190432492, 
1309.97105807522, 5863.24413932713, 84798.6701470358, 5287.89543614681, 
7019.68464118458, 207555.54211305, 42610.6785141417, 57455.2766420949, 
50880.0662736183, 8562.70774978471, 35615.0812816442, 3209.61081796767, 
13425.7891844031, 10172.0898252207, 25135.1384491464, 10171.5875982993, 
24546.3331711539, 20219.2191239651, 12492.0819211004, 19829.1935665882, 
10538.3674396562, 860.212193244676, 10441.8877791697, 109944.342344373, 
10130.4848607536, 38399430.0758622, 54346.1819763583, 60588.7451272658, 
10333339.8435353, 166914.291830525, 15106.291762901, 6992.51143191634, 
2096.00364208704, 178873.707038741, 32430.7567673094, 828119.280778115, 
172465.345148761, 2608478.34637721, 975944.341821359, 129890.525779898, 
781459.183975379, 13967.9236719995, 1460.95459419176, 1239.25223987981, 
2006.16751711888, 579.408605356926, 567.392719967148, 10646.2491986802, 
15849.8055842179, 15533.2886586566, 9405.82927410387, 30004.8039316661, 
5970.2054602464, 959.45168395392, 10588.6969072962, 7797.41788929008, 
11103.6195368155, 11422.3263920103, 11030.0357536182, 11005.3874434708, 
10256.8119809788, 11665.7731598811, 6780.08819348487, 939.441815889167, 
10049.3382667714, 17194.9845438908, 2105.35872638104, 15962587.4508949, 
2681.40283207019, 8290.02901841903, 199873.949286869, 14846.7790432671, 
10800.3647727473, 7104.21565574377, 1878.9292703595, 370849.323130881, 
22336.8687091073, 189194.987574215, 62353.0494427796, 2465448.35656496, 
443041.875133795), Afghanistan = c(304848.2, 1244.815, 5992.698, 
18010.06, 2975.027, 6331.944, 5160.831, 5384.333, 5747.278, 1392.815, 
10046.36, 6304.916, 11137.87, 10923.54, 36934.41, 10822.21, 8730.08, 
15105.91, 5966.117, 1117.582, 26.16316, 1.83796, 0.4187321, 0.7053242, 
16.82224, 2.368265, 2.229667, 2.969031, 0.4339618, 3.330972, 
0.1409332, 0.3907028, 2.256146, 0.4993595, 0.2239593, 0.8452328, 
0.4606935, 0.2311659, 0.4483911, 3.229056, 0.1869243, 14.26183, 
0.6368992, 0.1774615, 855.0543, 2.059841, 0.9784637, 326.125, 
2.480306, 0.6295102, 0.2723101, 0.009939627, 2.58328, 0.7858758, 
4.796921, 2.209655, 29.30604, 7.516025, 2.180713, 15.07286, 1.155397, 
0.03922217, 0.6618161, 0.3569212, 0.5384865, 0.156222, 3.320798, 
2.33509, 1.42815, 1.389516, 3.446843, 1.356888, 0.1334601, 0.510716, 
2.723687, 0.3888807, 0.4487993, 0.8531269, 0.6789875, 0.4435601, 
0.4159068, 3.614623, 0.3341556, 7.505752, 0.1033085, 0.08569755, 
972.7443, 0.1132736, 0.1158019, 2.354941, 0.2283046, 0.4196883, 
0.2569963, 0.01133495, 5.883291, 1.139181, 1.037388, 0.6386013, 
38.7435, 3.419991), Albania = c(3.535969, 0.03840783, 0.3863751, 
0.9954086, 0.08775854, 0.2030882, 1.391618, 0.5245008, 0.6190842, 
0.05073775, 0.3891475, 0.6727891, 0.1539272, 0.1706042, 0.5426898, 
0.1037151, 0.1823552, 0.2115925, 1.069002, 0.1062371, 3.949615, 
79527.31, 5061.744, 5606.964, 140981.7, 27107.64, 33462.2, 31183.07, 
4460.67, 21130.07, 2729.427, 10630.79, 8044.345, 22253.97, 9347.96, 
18225.96, 18097.29, 10439.65, 17669.2, 7737.212, 658.327, 2512.097, 
0.04379642, 0.007626944, 120.1914, 0.8615488, 0.4047151, 38.60637, 
1.123844, 0.1297725, 0.09295459, 0.002695269, 0.5615575, 0.7208675, 
1.350622, 0.3834361, 6.671941, 2.181208, 0.3419616, 1.298375, 
0.6230328, 0.02060596, 0.7954482, 0.1158716, 0.1792077, 0.05296581, 
0.9807616, 0.7176638, 0.4338842, 0.4336918, 1.129224, 0.4319445, 
0.04283256, 0.1534184, 0.7950113, 0.1193977, 0.1371983, 0.2555027, 
0.1975643, 0.1304942, 0.1132505, 1.009906, 0.1040789, 1.761093, 
0.02053985, 0.01377083, 54.03197, 0.05894175, 0.06595316, 0.9770419, 
0.1309219, 0.09237173, 0.1061737, 0.004385261, 1.031491, 0.6977874, 
0.4370498, 0.1476074, 8.667269, 1.531756), Algeria = c(5.240079, 
0.02104366, 0.5161704, 1.742304, 0.1884929, 0.638416, 0.3971941, 
0.5894792, 0.5243543, 0.09268831, 0.3778295, 0.8218906, 0.3903957, 
0.2782294, 1.946016, 0.2005679, 0.4673061, 0.46685, 1.315667, 
0.1372425, 5.728609, 14.15439, 0.6593845, 4.430993, 153.2115, 
35.62573, 92.96048, 52.28874, 8.492265, 32.08374, 1.774228, 7.498232, 
4.302572, 5.717841, 1.817346, 18.18068, 4.45664, 5.554349, 5.279886, 
5.870353, 0.4191698, 17.09926, 107132.8, 9887.484, 33714360, 
37499.33, 44093.85, 7940498, 117407.7, 9193.506, 4680.662, 2018.159, 
152113.8, 25992.47, 691562.8, 151294.7, 2163505, 848482.5, 102530.9, 
690073.7, 11346.21, 1308.455, 98.49957, 1.596688, 0.8939674, 
0.5979496, 12.63072, 17.78408, 26.27299, 10.60669, 36.0613, 7.210763, 
0.8374489, 4.829583, 4.684588, 2.309686, 2.157866, 8.470586, 
3.90022, 4.690984, 3.752759, 5.94401, 0.658466, 9.524497, 0.4095283, 
0.09161661, 2198.32, 0.6536236, 1.393105, 58.27179, 3.16544, 
3.330465, 1.636288, 0.06272295, 31.69208, 1.537006, 6.454557, 
2.202606, 287.937, 26.93717), Andorra = c(2.046408, 0.03199265, 
0.1913253, 0.6384646, 0.04210553, 0.05989684, 0.08395811, 0.08547009, 
0.1640007, 0.02629837, 0.06544481, 0.5198038, 0.0704934, 0.07354977, 
0.2318274, 0.05006094, 0.05805839, 0.07343344, 0.8471854, 0.08000277, 
3.281725, 1.166039, 0.1937104, 0.5849786, 14.64168, 2.014269, 
1.634169, 2.62503, 0.4598703, 3.004348, 0.1156719, 0.3324458, 
2.258714, 0.4214368, 0.1890398, 0.6775366, 0.4166179, 0.1967594, 
0.2213797, 3.279177, 0.1841389, 18.42281, 0.06572487, 0.0151666, 
241.5491, 0.734705, 0.5635472, 68.69543, 3.025981, 0.328492, 
0.1079413, 0.004644561, 1.220245, 0.776872, 4.995991, 0.5595545, 
22.07305, 5.319428, 0.9709488, 2.607332, 0.4908999, 0.02019178, 
0.5850328, 1497.731, 217.3481, 378.3719, 6415.105, 10549.02, 
10058.02, 6282.365, 16703.89, 3597.702, 744.6967, 9176.902, 5960.622, 
10163.73, 10653.15, 8799.109, 9645.094, 8923.656, 10560.27, 4362.44, 
687.0441, 5951.223, 0.01764571, 0.01243527, 41.01675, 0.04743286, 
0.05422601, 0.7896524, 0.1068679, 0.07563721, 0.08683252, 0.003704872, 
0.8285007, 0.5872343, 0.3658586, 0.1194013, 7.110707, 1.272627
), Angola = c(7.126427, 0.02126276, 0.7013776, 2.584582, 0.2207993, 
0.6455885, 0.5102651, 0.673658, 0.7199301, 0.1172209, 0.4537595, 
1.497391, 0.4881724, 0.3670951, 2.803086, 0.2650796, 0.6734943, 
0.5744068, 2.549689, 0.2411082, 13.97644, 3.896676, 0.5745994, 
1.517034, 45.23805, 6.866533, 8.479498, 9.423369, 1.715862, 9.02622, 
0.3268822, 1.231526, 4.494482, 1.333423, 0.5345557, 2.800145, 
1.197053, 0.8376675, 1.132491, 6.272173, 0.3792077, 28.0768, 
1.509137, 0.1199938, 2864.661, 11.52246, 6.664335, 1731.045, 
22.18162, 2.835002, 1.308098, 0.05257571, 13.34905, 4.500684, 
29.18065, 8.044516, 211.2769, 45.41144, 12.96821, 51.85862, 4.30742, 
0.1704663, 3.274468, 0.9248837, 1.163733, 0.4030822, 7.497041, 
6.648192, 7.311064, 4.187048, 11.8977, 3.649344, 0.4054804, 1.667877, 
5.738257, 1.079308, 1.176356, 3.087699, 1.857479, 1.600233, 1.335246, 
7.249851, 0.7536257, 12.16895, 16902.28, 2053.868, 14629320, 
2176.549, 7247.814, 167657.8, 12729.29, 8228.971, 5893.646, 1834.933, 
348980.5, 21047.25, 182549, 60673.71, 2279856, 421157.8)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("V2", 
"V3", "V4", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V11", "V12", "V14", "V15", 
"V16", "V17", "V18", "V20", "V21", "V23", "V24", "V25", "V26", 
"V27", "V28", "V29", "V30", "V32", "V33", "V34", "V35", "V37", 
"V38", "V40", "V41", "V42", "V43", "V44", "V46", "V47", "V49", 
"V50", "V51", "V52", "V53", "V54", "V55", "V56", "V58", "V59", 
"V60", "V61", "V63", "V64", "V66", "V67", "V68", "V69", "V70", 
"V72", "V73", "V75", "V76", "V77", "V78", "V79", "V80", "V81", 
"V82", "V84", "V85", "V86", "V87", "V89", "V90", "V92", "V93", 
"V94", "V95", "V96", "V98", "V99", "V101", "V102", "V103", "V104", 
"V105", "V106", "V107", "V108", "V110", "V111", "V112", "V113", 
"V115", "V116", "V118", "V119", "V120", "V121", "V122", "V124", 
"V125"))
```

As you can see, one country has multiple rows but just one column. For each row, a "Total" value is calculated by summing all the values from column 5 to column 194.

My aim is to calculate the Net Total, subtracting the corresponding country column from the total. For example, the first 26 rows are assigned to Afghanistan. I want to subtract from their "Total", the value of the 5th column (that corresponds to the same country). The second 26 are assigned to Albania, so the subtraction must occur between "total" and the 6th column. Etc.Etc.

The expected output should look like this (example is tentative, as the original data.frame is huge):

| name | code | cluster | sector | Total | Net total | Afghanistan | Albania |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Industries | Agriculture | 100 | 92 | 8 | 1 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Industries | Fishing | 105 | 99 | 6 | 2 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Industries | Mining | 98 | 96 | 2 | 3 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Industries | Textiles | 101 | 80 | 21 | 4 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Industries | Wood | 90 | 79 | 11 | 5 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Industries | Petroleum | 101 | 100 | 1 | 1 |
| Afghanistan | AFG | Industries | Metal | 50 | 30 | 20 | 3 |

What is important is that "Net Total" is calculated as "Total" - "Afghanistan" but only for the Afghanistan rows. In fact, "Net total" for another country's rows should be calculated as "Total" - "another country" columns.

How can I code this kind of operation?  I would prefer a code that links the subtraction to the country name rather than the column number, as I noticed that there are 190 country columns but only 171 different countries in the "name" column.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Updated. Unfortunately the data.frame is big, so i can just do small examples with tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below code -

```
df$net_total <- df$Total - as.numeric(df[cbind(1:nrow(df), match(df$name, names(df)))])
```

Comment: I literally just tried the same code and it worked. Thank you very much anyway.